# Firebase Unexpected JSON Response when device is offline

Tags: android, json, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using HTTP server and this is my message via the firebase server

```
$fcm = array
(
    'to' => $stored_token,
    'priority' => 'high',
    'time_to_live' => 0,
    'data' => array
    (
        'msg' => 0
    )
);
```

time_to_live is 0, means it should be delivered right away or discarded, which means when device is offline is should get

```
error:Unavailable
```

but this is the server from FCM server :

> {
>     "multicast_id": 7.0206465789357e+18,
>     "success": 1,
>     "failure": 0,
>     "canonical_ids": 0,
>     "results": [
>       {
>         "message_id": "0:1472135754209293%d42090b5f9fd7ecd"
>       }
>     ]
>   }

The message is being sent for high priority and time to live:0 seconds and device is offline.

Why is this happening?

Comment: As far as I know you are getting a success response because the message was successfully processed by FCM server. But it does not indicate that your message was delivered. Maybe the message was discarded if the device was offline because of the time_to_live=0.

Comment: well for time_to_live:0 , it should return error if device is offline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table 5 in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#interpret-downstream) for FCM HTTP Server Protocol indicates that `failure` count in the response is the

> Number of messages that could not be processed

The reasons for processing failure are listed in Table 9.  All the reasons are related to a problem with the request parameters, such as invalid format, value missing, etc.  Your request is valid, so is counted as a success.

In your post, you say "This behavior is against as stated in the documents".  Please update your post to include a link to the document that state a delivery failure should be counted as a processing failure.